# Empty params - RoR

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the next view

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag ({controller: "nodes", action: "new"}), :id => "users_search" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :autocomplete => 'off' %>
  <div id='users'>
    <%= render 'users' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%=form_for @node do |f| %>
  **<%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>**
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id  %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :ocuped, :value => true %>
  <%= f.text_field :custom_node_name %>
  <%= f.check_box :terms_of_service,{}, true,false %>
  <%= f.submit "Pagar", class: "button postfix" %>
<% end %>
```

The nodes_controller.rb

```
def new
@node = Node.new  
@parent = Node.search(params[:search]).where(:ocuped => true)

if not @users.nil?
  if @users.count == 1
    @node_incomplete = @users.nodes.where(" sons < ? AND ocuped = ?",2,true).first
  else
    @node_incomplete = @users.first.nodes.where(" sons < ? AND ocuped = ?",2,true).first
  end
  @son_of_incompleted_node = @node_incomplete.children
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render }
end
```

end

_users.html.erb

```
<% if not @parent.nil? %>
<% @parent.each do |u| %>
    <ul class="inline-list">
        <li class="img-simple" style = "text-align: center; background-image: url('<%= u.user.profile_img %>')"></li>
            <li style="display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"><h6><%= u.user.name %></h6><p><%= u.user.email %></p></li>
    </ul>
    **<% params[:parent_id] = u.id %>**
<% end %>
```

new.js.erb

```
$('#users').html('<%= escape_javascript(render("users")) %>');
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .

$(function() {
  $("#users_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#users_search").attr("action"), $("#users_search").serialize(), null, "script");
return false;
  });
});
```

node.js.cofee

```
jQuery ->
  # Ajax search on keyup
  $('#users_search input').keyup( ->
$.get($("#users_search").attr("action"), $("#users_search").serialize(), null, 'script')
false
  )
```

Everything works fine except that when I send the second form the parameter " parent_id " is empty , and creates the node with the value " parent_id = nil " .

[Image](http://www.subeimagenes.com/img/join-1370688.png)

Comment: What HTML is being rendered for the form? What does the request sent by the browser look like?

Comment: This is what you're asking me ? Sorry , I'm new in "ruby" . The form rendering to http://localhost:3000/nodes.

Comment: I mean, what HTML is being sent to the browser (try View Source), and when the form is submitted, what data does the browser send to the server in the request (look in the Rails log or your browser's Developer Tools).

Comment: `<% params[:parent_id] = u.id %>` not sure what this line means... I have never seen that in rails

Comment: How do I assign the value of u.id to: parent_id ? I think that's really my question

Comment: If you want a value to be sent to the server as a param, then it needs to be present in a form field that's submitted or in the data given with an Ajax request. If the request is coming from a form being submitted, then put the value in a hidden form field and it will be available in `params` with the name of the form field.